# Ag-Grid how to start loading records from the 500th?

Tags: ag-grid

I have a Ag-grid configured to work in infinity scroll

In the documentation, i found [this example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#example-using-cache-api-methods), which shows how to make a jump to the 500th record

But I'm looking for a way to start loading the grid directly to the 500th record

Maybe there is a property to set in the grid?

Or should I put in some event this code:

```
jumpTo500() {
  if (this.gridApi.getInfiniteRowCount() < 501) {
    this.gridApi.setInfiniteRowCount(501, false);
  }
  this.gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(500);
}
```

Which?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ensureIndexVisible` on `onGridReady` stage:

```
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    this.gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(499);  <--- add this line
```

> **Note** : `this.gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(numberValue)` number value should be less than `infiniteInitialRowCount` atleast for 1

```
infiniteInitialRowCount = 1000 - initial config

this.gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(999) - max
```

> Update: another possible way via `firstDataRendered`
>
> **`firstDataRendered`**   Fired the first time data is rendered into the grid.

```
(firstDataRendered)="firstDataRendered($event)"
...
firstDataRendered(){
    this.gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(499);
}
```

Comment: No, it does not work, because on the "onGridReady" event the data does not exist yet and that property works only with the data already present.

In fact, it returns this error: "invalid row index for ensureIndexVisible: 499"

Comment: [Check here](https://plnkr.co/edit/UO2dh2?p=preview) just added `params.api.ensureIndexVisible(499);` after `dataSource`

Comment: There is a new event called firstDataRendered. Fired the first time data is rendered into the grid. I would suggest trying this one instead

Comment: Tried the firstDataRendered solution but still didn't work for me. We're on ag-grid v20 so perhaps need to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

[The ag-grid has a bug in infinity scroll mode](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2704)

They are working to fix the bug

The solution proposed here is the best workaround I have found so far

But it does not permanently resolve the performance bug

In fact, looking in the logs you can see that the program always makes a first unnecessary request, to view the first 100 records

Only then, the workaround requires the correct records from 400 to 500

Comment: I just added some more information in the github: I can see that this is being tracked in both places.

Note that we wouldn't consider this a bug, but a feature request :)

In any case, the solution highlighted in the stackoverflow is a decent workaround until you have this feature request to allow you to do this out of the box.

I hope this clarifies this...

Comment: To summarise, the solution mentioned by @un.spike is still a fully acceptable workaround

Comment: I edited the solution to better explain the bug on the performance